# javascript eval cannot understand some RegEx in string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, eval

The `eval` seems to not understand the `RegEx` at all.

I got this `string` to Check for entered `YEAR` in the *input* field.

The *RegEx* should `match` something like: **2010**, **1980** or any Year between **1900** to **2099**.

***RegEx***: `^(19|20)\d{2}$` works well in raw `javascript` something like:

```
var testStr = /^(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(2013) //logs true
```

but `testStr2 = eval("/^(19|20)\d{2}$/").test(2013) //logs false`

*Please see fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/zq30puzm/

This is being used in:

```
"getYear":{
                        "regex":"/^(19|20)\d{2}$/",
                        "alertText":"* Invalid Year"
},
```

It keeps on printing the *Error* event when the *input data* is a deserving one.

What could be the issue?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

*Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/zq30puzm/

Comment: BTW: `eval` is evil. `eval("/.../")` is functionally equivalent to `new Regexp("...")`, but much slower and less safe. Almost everything in JavaScript can be done without `eval` - and should be.

Comment: Great Advice: can you tell how to do that with `new RegExp`? I tried; `var str=new RegExp("/^(19|20)\d{2}$/"); str.test(2013) //logs false.` How best to do it using `new RegExp()`??

Comment: Same answer as Jake King's: with `new Regexp` you're using a string literal as a parameter, and in a string literal backslashes need to be escaped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the string version, you need to escape the backslash.

```
var testStr2 = eval("/^(19|20)\\d{2}$/").test(2013);
```

In regular expression literals, escaping backslashes is unnecessary (unless you need a literal backslash), but in a string, `\d` simply becomes the character `d` without escaping.

---

As a note of caution, `eval` should really be avoided at all costs. It's highly unlikely that you ever need it, and using it can always be dangerous without ample care to ensure that it can't be abused for malicious purposes. Furthermore, if your regex is malformed or some other error occurs, you won't get a helpful error message, it will likely just break in strange ways.

If you can, use RegExp literals! They are convenient and reliable, and you don't have to do any unnecessary escaping:

```
/^(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(2013);
```

If you need the regex from a string, use the constructor instead of `eval`. It will do the same thing, but more safely.

```
new RegExp("^(19|20)\\d{2}$").test(2013);
```

Comment: One small issue - RegExp literals can still require escaping e.g. `var result = "thing".match(/^\/\//)` vs `eval('var result = "thing".match(/^\/\//)')`